# Pass PHP variable to javascript including quotes and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

This question has been asked a few times, and the answer seems to be to use `json_encode` but this is not working as my string contains a few more things than quotes.

This is the PHP string:

```
<img src="test.jpg" :class="{ 'add-class': comment == 1, 'another-class': comment == 2 }" x-on:click="submit()">
```

The `:class` and `x-on:` are [AlpineJS](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine) attributes in case you were wondering (check it out, it's really cool!).

This PHP string is dynamically generated and I would like to pass it to a javascript variable, shown here as `jsVariable`:

```
<script>
function test() {
  return {
    jsVariable: ,
    anotherVariable: true,
  }
}
</script>
```

Update
If I use `jsVariable: <?php echo json_encode($php_variable); ?>,` I get SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&' on that line.

If I use `jsVariable: '<?php echo json_encode($php_variable); ?>',` (added single quotes) then the variable is parsed as a string and not as HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode()`:

```
<script>
function test() {
  return {
    jsVariable: <?php echo json_encode($php_variable); ?>,
    anotherVariable: true,
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe it's AlpineJS that causes this not to work then. If I use `json_encode` when the variable is `<strong>test</strong>` it works and the html is parsed. However if the variable is what I have in my question, then it looks like it's parsed as a string, as it's wrapped in double quotes. I'm using AlpineJS's `x-html`, maybe this should be a new / different question if that is causing the behaviour.

Comment: Actually, it's not really doing what I'm expecting. I've updated the question.

Comment: This is just for generating raw JavaScript, it won't work for creating framework code.

Answer (score 0):

If you just use ASCII coding, you may give base64 encoding a try.

PHP encode the string into base64, and Javascript to decode, like this:

```
<script>
function test(){
  var str = '<?php echo base64_encode($str);?>';
  return {
    jsVariable: atob(str),
    anotherVariable: true
  }
}

alert(test().jsVariable)
</script>
```

Hope this helps.